# Issue with JavaMail MMS text to email read

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have been building an application that uses JavaMail to send emergency messages out to co-workers. This application also allows them to respond. The application reads all messages received and does work based on the information in said text.

In the previous months we have had no issues until recently (past 1 week or so) when reading MMS messages. **Plain Text messages work fine.**

Here is the error we are receiving when we grab an MMS message from a user:

//this is all printed logs and no error here
//however the information may help you

```
type="application/smil"
boundary=__CONTENT_64564_PART_BOUNDARY__33243242__;
multipart/MIXED;
This is a Multipart
---------------------------

error reading email: java.lang.ClassCastException:
javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart incompatible with javax.mail.Multipart
```

I have even tried switching my code here:

```
else if (m.isMimeType("multipart/*")) {
    System.out.println("This is a Multipart");
    System.out.println("---------------------------");
    //Multipart mmp = (Multipart) m.getContent(); //Current code for error above
    MimeMultipart mmp = (MimeMultipart) m.getContent();
    int count = mmp.getCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        boolean completedMultipart = false;
        completedMultipart = dumpMultiPart(mmp.getBodyPart(i), smsAddress);
        if(completedMultipart){
            completedTask = true;
        }
    }
}
```

However this still returns this error:

```
error reading email: java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart
incompatible with javax.mail.MimeMultipart
```

I have read that Classpaths could be an issue, however I believe I have things set up correctly. Here is an image of the classpath setup:

**Class path**

[image]

Comment: You have 2 versions of JavaMail in your classpath: `javax.mail-1.5.5.jar` and `mail-1.4.7.jar`. Try removing one.

Comment: I am deploying the change now. I should note that I have tried this before. Will update in a second with results

Comment: After removing mail.1.4.7.jar and leaving only javax.mail-1.5.5.jar, the error still occurs.

Comment: Maybe another copy is sneaking in? What does the WEB-INF/lib directory of the final WAR look like?

Comment: It only contains the .jars in the pic in my original message, MINUS the mail.1.4.7.jar that i removed. The odd thing about this whole issue is that it runs fine on my localhost, but when i deploy to IBM Bluemix site, it fails.

Comment: It's definitely a classpath problem.  Are you deploying to a Java EE application server?  If so, the server already includes JavaMail and you shouldn't include it in your application.

Comment: WOW You could totally be right Bill!! It is a Java EE server! I needed it in my classpath to run on my local machine, but this totally makes sense. I will try it now. Will the imports work if i remove them from the initial classpath though?

Comment: @BillShannon I still have not been able to get this to work... When I removed the javamail api from my path it stopped working entirely. Not sure what to do anymore..

Comment: Exactly what Java EE server are you deploying to and exactly what error message are you getting when your app doesn't include the JavaMail jar file?

Comment: Bill - I am deploying my application to bluemix. The server is a Liberty for Java server [link](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/starters/liberty-for-java/) It seems that there is a hidden .jar that I am unaware of somewhere apart from the classpath. When I removed it from the classpath, the application was still unable to find the javax.mail.search.FlagTerm import

Comment: Hi Bill, Is there a better way for me to get in contact with you today? I have tested my code again, and it runs fine without adding the bluemix or websphere library. however, when i add these libraries it fails. if i take out the javamail that i added to the classpath, there are errors that it can not find javax.mail.search.SearchTerm. If there is a better way for us to speak about this please let me know