# calling javamail api from Liberty server on bluemix

Tags: java, import, jakarta-mail, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

Last week I had a classpath issue with my javamail.jar. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38383055/issue-with-javamail-mms-text-to-email-read?noredirect=1#comment64184020_38383055)

I found that on Bluemix, the liberty server I am deploying to contains a javamail api (java ee server), and that is where my classpath issue is coming from. However, if I am to remove the javamail-1.5.5.jar from my classpath, I receive errors stating that it cannot find other things (the first being: javax.mail.search.SearchTerm). I cannot remove MY imported javamail fully due to this error.

I have three questions:

1. Where is the javamail api on the websphere server for bluemix located, so that I could call the import directly, instead of my own .jar
2. What is the version of javamail that Liberty has on it.
3. Can you see any way of solving this better?

I can put some of my code on here as well if that would be helpful, however its a pretty standard email reader.

Thanks so much for your time!

-Tony

Comment: are you just publishing your war file to bluemix, or a server package? (do you have a configured server.xml of any kind?)

Comment: I am only pushing a .war to the server, and have no server.xml going with it. I am unsure as to where I would put it. I even tried including a websphere library, however the websphere library did not contain the server.xml flie in it. Apologies if this library is not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're compiling your application you need access to the JavaMail classes, but when you package your application you don't want to include those classes.  Depending on what build system you're using, there are different ways to do this.  In Maven you can use a "provided" dependency, for example.

Comment: Hi Bill, I am not using maven. However, I have found this link. I am just not sure how to go about adding the server.xml file so that bluemix will use it:
[link](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS7K4U_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.zseries.doc/ae/twlp_classloader_alt_api.html)

It details how to over-ride an api on the server.

Comment: What are you using to build and package your app?  You shouldn't need to override the API on the server.

Comment: Hi Bill, I was able to fix this issue by deploying to a tomcat server instead of a liberty server on bluemix. thanks for your help though

Comment: That's not so much a fix as a workaround.  That only works because Tomcat is not a Java EE application server and thus doesn't include JavaMail.  In this case, packaging JavaMail with your app works.  But it sounds like you still haven't figured out how to properly build and package an app that uses Java EE APIs.

Comment: That is correct Bill. I will revisit the issue in the future, but for now this suffice well enough for my needs